# Javascript lerp fuction not giving accurate answers

Tags: javascript, math

I need to interpolate between three different ranges, (1,1.3),(.72,1) ,
(1.4,1.9)->(1,1.05) and (2,3)->(1.05,1.1) where the first two items are x values, and the 2nd two are the y's, but the function doesn't seem to return the right values, even for the given points,

Any help appreciated.

```js
function lerp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x) {
  return y1 + (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}

function savings(t) {
  let res;
  let m;
  if (t >= 1 || t <= 1.3) {
    res = lerp(1, 1.3, .72, 1, t);
    console.log(res)
  }
  if (t >= 1.4 || t <= 1.9) {
    res = lerp(1.4, 1.9, 1, 1.05, t);
    console.log(res)
  }
  if (t >= 2 || t <= 3) {
    res = lerp(2, 3, 1.05, 1.1, t);
    console.log(res)
  }

  return res;
}

savings(1.3)
```

Comment: do you have some values to test with the wanted results?

Comment: You do know that, while providing `x` as argument in `lerp` it is actually not used in the formula.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, I want to be able to get the original values provided back

Comment: @Mouser thanks, what is the correct forumula? this was one I found online

Comment: what is the wanted result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the range by using the [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) operator instead of [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), which checks only one comparison.

That means all values of `t` takes the first condition until all values are greater or equal than one.

```js
function lerp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x) {
    return y1 + (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}

function savings(t) {
    if (t >= 1 && t <= 1.3) return lerp(1, 1.3, .72, 1, t);
    if (t >= 1.4 && t <= 1.9) return lerp(1.4, 1.9, 1, 1.05, t);
    if (t >= 2 && t <= 3) return lerp(2, 3, 1.05, 1.1, t);
}

console.log(savings(1.3));
```

Comment: thank you for literally saving me from a 8th grade IT class problem that a CS grad somehow screwed up in a large companies website.